# How do I set Django/South to use transactions in migrations?

Tags: mysql, django, django-south

I'm using Django with MySQL and South, and everything's just dandy...until something goes wrong with a migration. Then I get an error which often damages or destroys my database, and along the line gives me:

```
 ! Since you have a database that does not support running
 ! schema-altering statements in transactions, we have had 
 ! to leave it in an interim state between migrations.
```

All of my database tables are InnoDB, which as far as I know supports transactions. What do I have to do to get South to use transactions with its migrations?

Comment: MySQL docs on "Statements That Cannot Be Rolled Back" http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cannot-roll-back.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point of the error message is that MySQL *doesn't* support transactions when you're altering schemas. MySQL only supports transactions when you're creating/updating/selecting data. Read carefully what is written about MySQL under Database-Specific Issues section on [South website](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/databaseapi.html?highlight=mysql).

If you do want to use model migrations you can switch to PostgreSQL which will be completely transparent to you with Django. The only changes are to the *settings.py* database section (and the PostgreSQL installation of course).